# How to set the default date for my jquery month picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need a month picker in my web page. Here is what I found here to get the month picker.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".monthPicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));
        }
    });
});

<input type="text" name="processingDate" id="processingDate" class="monthPicker" />
```

Now I need make some change to set current date (month and year) as the default date to the text box. Anyone know how to do this?

Update: Maybe I didn't say it in right way. Basically when I first bring up the page, I'd like to see the current month and year already set in the text box (before I bring up the monthpicker to pick a month and year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(".monthPicker").datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(".monthPicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: new Date(),   // <---- Put it here
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));
    }
});
```

Comment: LOL! Try harder next time ;)